# Can sklearn pipelines be used to train a different model for each value of a categorical feature?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is it possible to split a dataset on a categorical feature, and train a different model for each value of the splitting feature using [make_pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) (or [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html))?